# xna not working anymore

Tags: c#, xna

I wanted to change from Reach to HiDef and when i tried that i got this error :

```
Error   1   Building content threw AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.FbxImporter.Cleanup()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.FbxImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentImporter`1.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.ImportAssetDirectly(BuildItem item, String importerName)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.ImportAsset(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAssetWorker(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAsset(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAndLoadAsset(BuildItem item, BuildItem requestingItem)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.ImportAssetViaCache(BuildItem item, String importerName)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.ImportAsset(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAssetWorker(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.BuildAsset(BuildItem item)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.BuildCoordinator.RunTheBuild()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Tasks.BuildContent.RemoteProxy.RunTheBuild(BuildCoordinatorSettings settings, TimestampCache timestampCache, ITaskItem[] sourceAssets, String[]& outputContent, String[]& rebuiltContent, String[]& intermediates, Dictionary`2& dependencyTimestamps, KeyValuePair`2[]& warnings)   C:\Users\alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BG_3D_27.10.10_2\BG_3D\BG_3D\BG_3DContent\Models\ship.FBX   BG_3D
```

When i tried to go back to Reach, the same error occurred . I thought that i may have messed the code in some way so i tried to run a 2-day old back-up and the same error appeared . What could it be ?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your FBX model. Have you updated software you use for generating it? You can try reverting it to older version.

XNA importer is probably a bit outdated. You can use converters to change FBX file to older format.